# How to make all the space near a group of SVG paths into a clickable link, not just the SVG stroke itself?

Tags: html, css, svg, click, anchor

I have several svg `<path>` elements grouped together into two seperate group `<g>` elements (IDs are `po` and `ph`). Both are inside another group, and everything is inside a single `<svg>`.

The HTML looks like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <link href="stripped_back_CSS.css" rel="stylesheet">
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="container">
         <div id="content" class="hide">
            <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 595.3 841.9" style="enable-background:new 0 0 595.3 841.9;" xml:space="preserve">
               <style type="text/css">
                  .st5{fill:none;stroke:red;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
               </style>
               <g id="page">
                  <g id="po">
                     <path class="st5" d="M382.1,465.4c1.1,2.6,1.3,7.3,1.4,9.2c0.1-3.3-4-13,2.7-13.1c5.3-0.1,4.4,8.5-2.7,6.7"/>
                     <path class="st5" d="M395.3,464.1c-4.9,0.9-2.3,8,2.3,5.7c4.7-2.3-0.3-7.5-3.8-3.8"/>
                  </g>
                  <g id="ph">
                     <path class="st5" d="M392.4,522c0,3.2,0.4,6.6,1.1,9.7c-3.7-3.9-2.3-16.4,4.9-11.3c4.1,2.8-3.3,7.3-6.6,5.5"/>
                     <path class="st5" d="M402.8,519.3c1,3.1,0.3,6.4,2.2,9.3"/>
                     <path class="st5" d="M410.5,517.6c-1.2,3.6-0.9,8.7,1.1,12.1"/>
                     <path class="st5" d="M403.9,525.3c1.8-0.8,4-1.9,6-2.2"/>
                  </g>
               </g>
            </svg>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

and the CSS file like this:

```
#content {
    text-align: center
}

#content svg {
    background: #fff;
    width: auto;
    height: 152vh;
    margin: 8vh 0 8vh 0;
    box-shadow: -9px -9px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .12);
    max-width: 90%
}
```

This produces the following svg characters:

[image]

I would like to make each of these groups of text into a clickable link. However, if I try to surround the group tags simply with `<a></a>` tags then the text stroke is indeed clickable BUT the space between the stroke is not. For example, if the cursor was hovered *inside* the letter 'O' then at that position nothing is clickable. How can I make the "general area" of each group of characters clickable?

Thank you!

Comment: draw a visibility hidden rect on top of them and make that clickable via pointer-events

Comment: I am not sure exactly how to implement your suggestion - could you post an example? I am a total beginner! Thanks.

Comment: If I place a <rect> element directly inside the group (just before the <path>) then the rectangle appears relative to the main container - not relative to the group element itself.

Comment: In your case the rect should be `<rect x="381" y="460" width="20" height="15" fill="none" pointer-events="all"  />` In order to know the values for x y width and height use the method [getBBox()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGGraphicsElement/getBBox) on the group

Comment: @enxaneta Thanks - and where should the hyperlink anchor tags go? Around only <rect>, or everything in the group? or around the group <g> itself?

Comment: Around the `<g>`

Comment: Great thank you. What is the purpose of the pointer-events="all" property? It seems to me like it works without including that at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a transparent rect on top, or under, the other elements that you want to treat as a single link.  You'll probably find that on top (ie. later in the SVG file) causes fewer issues.  See below.

```
<g id="po">
  <path class="st5" d="M382.1,465.4c1.1,2.6,1.3,7.3,1.4,9.2c0.1-3.3-4-13,2.7-13.1c5.3-0.1,4.4,8.5-2.7,6.7"/>
  <path class="st5" d="M395.3,464.1c-4.9,0.9-2.3,8,2.3,5.7c4.7-2.3-0.3-7.5-3.8-3.8"/>
  <a xlink:href="http://www.stackoverflow.com" target="_blank">
    <rect x="382" y="461" width="18" height="14" fill="transparent"/>
  </a>
</g>
```

The `<a>` element could either be around the `<rect>`, around the `<g>`, or around all the children of the group. It doesn't really matter.

```css
#content {
    text-align: center
}

#content svg {
    background: #fff;
    width: auto;
    height: 152vh;
    margin: 8vh 0 8vh 0;
    box-shadow: -9px -9px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .12);
    max-width: 90%
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
         <div id="content" class="hide">
            <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 595.3 841.9" style="enable-background:new 0 0 595.3 841.9;" xml:space="preserve">
               <style type="text/css">
                  .st5{fill:none;stroke:red;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
               </style>
               <g id="page">
                  <g id="po">
                     <path class="st5" d="M382.1,465.4c1.1,2.6,1.3,7.3,1.4,9.2c0.1-3.3-4-13,2.7-13.1c5.3-0.1,4.4,8.5-2.7,6.7"/>
                     <path class="st5" d="M395.3,464.1c-4.9,0.9-2.3,8,2.3,5.7c4.7-2.3-0.3-7.5-3.8-3.8"/>
                     <a xlink:href="http://www.stackoverflow.com"">
                       <rect x="382" y="461" width="18" height="14" fill="transparent"/>
                     </a>
                  </g>
                  <g id="ph">
                     <path class="st5" d="M392.4,522c0,3.2,0.4,6.6,1.1,9.7c-3.7-3.9-2.3-16.4,4.9-11.3c4.1,2.8-3.3,7.3-6.6,5.5"/>
                     <path class="st5" d="M402.8,519.3c1,3.1,0.3,6.4,2.2,9.3"/>
                     <path class="st5" d="M410.5,517.6c-1.2,3.6-0.9,8.7,1.1,12.1"/>
                     <path class="st5" d="M403.9,525.3c1.8-0.8,4-1.9,6-2.2"/>
                     <a xlink:href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">
                       <rect x="391" y="517" width="21" height="15" fill="transparent"/>
                     </a>
                  </g>
               </g>
            </svg>
         </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Great thanks Paul for the complete answer. Do you know why other users are suggesting implementing the pointer-events="all" property? What is different about this?

Comment: You only really need that if you use `fill="none"`. Using `fill="transparent"` solves that problem because "transparent" is treated as an actual fill, and thus the browser thinks it is over something. If that makes sense.

`pointer-events="all"` tells the browser to pretend there is a fill, even if there isn't.

Comment: Finally, do you know if either of these methods is preferable in terms of how likely they are to be compatible with other browsers/devices? Or it's really just personal preference?

Comment: You should be fine. As long as the browser supports CSS3 you can use `transparent`. So that includes everything from IE9 or newer. https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-css_types_color_transparent.

Answer (score 2):

One of the easiest way to do this would be, to use an `<rect />` inside your `<g>`.
You can give `opacity` to be 0 and then write all your `<path>`. You can give the `<rect />`  height and width equal to the area you want clickable/ any mouse event.

```
           <g id="po">
               <rect x="" y="" width="" height="" style="fill-opacity:0; stroke-opacity:0" />
               <path class="st5" d="M382.1,465.4c1.1,2.6,1.3,7.3,1.4,9.2c0.1-3.3-4-13,2.7-13.1c5.3-0.1,4.4,8.5-2.7,6.7"/>
               <path class="st5" d="M395.3,464.1c-4.9,0.9-2.3,8,2.3,5.7c4.7-2.3-0.3-7.5-3.8-3.8"/>
           </g>
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of how to implement the clickable link?

Comment: My answer was regarding, how to make the area clickable,. If you are looking for how to add hyperlinks to that area, here's a great example: https://css-tricks.com/the-many-ways-to-link-up-shapes-and-images-with-html-and-css/#:~:text=The%20simplest%20way%20to%20make,SVG%20elements%20or%20just%20one.

Comment: Can you add a complete example to your answer and then I can accept it?

Comment: Should I wrap <a> tags around all elements inside the group? Or only the <rect> element? Or outside the group itself, to wrap the whole group?

Comment: Or should it be done with the pointer events property? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/pointer-events